# Need explanation for let-* directives in ng-template

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, single-page-application

I'm newbie in angular and right now working with some legacy code. In one component there is a table with let loop. Searched for it in internet but didn't understood it well.

```
<ng-template #itemTmpl let-data let-element="element">
  <ng-container *ngIf="data === 'route'"> {{ currentRouteSubject.value.number }} </ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngIf="data === 'name'">
    <ng-container *ngIf="!editRouteScheduleMap.has(element.id)"> {{ element[data] }} </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngIf="editRouteScheduleMap.has(element.id)">
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="editRouteScheduleMap.get(element.id).name" />
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngIf="data === 'requiredBusAmount'">
    <ng-container *ngIf="!editRouteScheduleMap.has(element.id)"> {{ element[data] }} </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngIf="editRouteScheduleMap.has(element.id)">
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="editRouteScheduleMap.get(element.id).requiredBusAmount" />
    </ng-container>
</ng-template>
```

can you explain me this let-data, let-element='element', and how it connected with source file

Answer (score 5):

The let-* attribute is a feature of the ng-template to inject a variable into the template by sourcing the variable's value from the context.

```
<ng-template let-data="sometext">
      <span>{{data}}</span>
</ng-template>
```

Maybe you can view this [article](https://netbasal.com/understanding-angular-structural-directives-659acd0f67e) to understand more about this

Comment: "sometext" is? the output should be?